# TinyMCE custom menu - Spellchecker language dropdown

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am implementing TinyMCE in my application and have created a custom menu bar. The problem that I am facing is that I do not know how I can add the languages dropdown for the [spellchecker pro plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/tinymcespellchecker/) to my menu bar.

**TinyMCE**

Version: `V4`

Source used in my app: [TinyMCE Source](https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js)

MenuControls: [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/editor-control-identifiers/#menucontrols)

---

My current setup:

```
export const editor = {
    elementpath: false, // Disable html display in bottom bar ('p >> span' for example)
    branding: false, // Disable 'powered by TinyMCE' text
    height: '100%',
    resize: false, // Disable editor resize
    fontsize_formats: '8pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt', // Font size options

    menu: {
        edit: {title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall'},
        insert: {title: 'Insert', items: 'image link media | charmap hr | pagebreak anchor toc'},
        format: {title: 'Format', items: 'removeformat bold italic italic strikethrough subscript superscript |  blockformats align'},
        tools: {title: 'Tools', items: 'visualchars searchreplace spellchecker translate'},
        table: {title: 'Table', items: 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | row column cell'},
    },

    toolbar1: font + ' | ' + list,
    toolbar2: formatting + ' | ' + align + ' table',
};
```

The result:
[image: Editor result]

But the misses the list of spellchecker languages:
[image: Tools with languages]

---

Does anyone know what key I should use for this dropdown? I cannot find it listed in the [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/editor-control-identifiers/#menucontrols) or in their [code](https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.js). It looks like the does not exist?

**Update**

I should have read the docs better. I read the docs of the 'spellchecker plugin' instead of the 'spelchecker pro plugin' which I ment. The answer is that you should add the key `spellcheckerlanguage` to your menu.

Comment: Care to share your code?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, added more code then just the one line that is creating the menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second screenshot appears to be one for the SpellChecker Pro premium plugin and not the open source Spellchecker plugin.

The SpellChecker Pro product includes the languages shown in that select list.  The open source Spellcheck plugin requires you to setup your own server side spelling engine and referencing those languages yourself.

Comment: I am indeed using the pro plugin, so it should be possible to select a language. The only problem is that I do not know what key for the menu I should use for my custom menu.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, I should have read you answer better. The problem was that I was reading the documentation for the spell checker and not the spell checker pro. I updated the link in my question and will accept your answer.